# Code output changes when adding id to nav item

Tags: html, css, output

I'm currently cleaning up my code for a responsive menu, but for some reason the output changes when I add the id to the nav item.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */


/*=========== MAIN CODE ===========*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

div#container {
  width: 100%;
}


/*=================================*/


/*=========== MAIN MENU ===========*/

div#menu-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
}

div#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
  display: none;
}


/* Hide the navigation menu by default */

.toggle + a,
.menu {
  display: none;
}


/* Stylinf the toggle lable */

.toggle {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.label {
  text-align: left;
}

.toggle:hover {}


/* Display Dropdown when clicked on Parent Lable */

[id^=drop]:checked + ul {
  display: block;
}

nav#main {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

nav#main:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

nav#main ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav#main ul li {
  display: block;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/* Hide Dropdown */

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: static;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/* Dropdown */

nav#main ul ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}


/* '+' = Dropdown symbol 
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }
*/


/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------- */

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  nav#main ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  /* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
  nav#main ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
  }
  nav#main ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
  }
  nav#main ul ul li {
    display: list-item;
  }
  /* Hide the navigation menu by default */
  .toggle + a,
  .menu {
    display: inherit;
  }
  .toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}


/*=================================*/
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div class="menu-wrap" id="wrapper">
      <nav id="main">
        <label for="drop" class="toggle label">
          <div id="hamburger">&#9776;</div>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Portfolio</label>
            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Photography</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Visuals</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Webdesign</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Videos</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Papers</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

I'm trying to add '#main' to the css nav items (because my nav item has the id 'main') so that the css code is specific for the main menu, since some of the pages of my website require a secondary menu and I want to keep those apart in my code, obviously. There are two css-items that change the output when changing nav to nav#main, the rest I could change without any issues:

```
nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

nav ul ul {
    display:none;
    position: static;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

The issues:
- When changing nav a to nav#main a: the portfolio tag is displayed double (both the a and the label one).
- When changing nav ul ul to nav#main ul ul: the click-action to display the dropdown underneath 'portfolio' doesn't work anymore.
The issues are seen this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2z9gdabt/1/

By adding an ID (or class, for that matter) I'm only calling on that specific element, right? So why does the output change when specifically calling that element, when there are no other nav elements?

I'm sure I'm missing something, but can someone explain to me why the output changes when adding an ID to the css code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue. Adding an id increases specificity, so your other rules that hide `.toggle + a` and show the submenu via `[id^=drop]:checked + ul` don't have enough specificity to override the default rules. Just add `nav#menu` to those selectors, too.

https://jsfiddle.net/2z9gdabt/2/

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */


/*=========== MAIN CODE ===========*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

div#container {
  width: 100%;
}


/*=================================*/


/*=========== MAIN MENU ===========*/

div#menu-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
}

div#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
  display: none;
}


/* Hide the navigation menu by default */

nav#main .toggle + a,
.menu {
  display: none;
}


/* Stylinf the toggle lable */

.toggle {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.label {
  text-align: left;
}

.toggle:hover {}


/* Display Dropdown when clicked on Parent Lable */

nav#main [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
  display: block;
}

nav#main {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

nav#main:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

nav#main ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav#main ul li {
  display: block;
}

nav#main a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/* Hide Dropdown */

nav#main ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: static;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/* Dropdown */

nav#main ul ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}


/* '+' = Dropdown symbol 
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }
*/


/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------- */

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  nav#main ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  /* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
  nav#main ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
  }
  nav#main ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
  }
  nav#main ul ul li {
    display: list-item;
  }
  /* Hide the navigation menu by default */
  .toggle + a,
  .menu {
    display: inherit;
  }
  .toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}


/*=================================*/
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div class="menu-wrap" id="wrapper">
      <nav id="main">
        <label for="drop" class="toggle label">
          <div id="hamburger">&#9776;</div>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Portfolio</label>
            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Photography</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Visuals</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Webdesign</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Videos</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Papers</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! So basically, when adding ID's etc. afterwards, you have to add them to every element with which the menu is mentioned in the css?

Comment: @Lisa potentially, CSS specificity is tricky. But for a rule to overwrite a rule later, it needs to have the same or higher specificity. It's a good idea to refer to rules consistently, so refer to them later in your css the same way you referred to them earlier in your css.